# Is it possible to see the source code of any api?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api

I would like to see the source code of any api/Web Api or web service.

Is it possible ? If yes, then how can I do that?

Comment: If you have access to the assembly then you could decompile it (if it is not obfuscated or otherwise protected)

Answer (score 0):

You can't see compiled code, you can only see some html with your browser (f12)